# Implementing a Custom 404 page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I just made a page that will act as my 404 landing page. However I do not know how to implement it. I am very new to HTML, anything helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Specifying a custom 404 page is done on your server.  What server type are you using?

Comment: more details may help

Comment: What do you mean by **implement it** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done server-side. Take a look at this article here, it should help solve your problem.

https://www.portent.com/blog/featured/create-a-great-404-page.htm

The article explains how you go into the server-side of your site and edit the 404 page.